# How to select text by word instead of characters?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change the text selection granularity to word.

For instance, if we have the text **"I am your father Luke"**

it will not be possible to select **"ur fat"**,
instead the selection will be **"your father"**.

I try to change the TextSelection behavior without success.

thanks

Comment: I work with a FlowDocumentScrollViewer, and I want something like the RichTextBox.AutoWordSelection property.

Comment: Your tags suggest that you are working with a `RichTextBox`. Replace it with a `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` tag or at least explain this in your question!

Answer (score 1):

You could always split your string via whitespace:

```
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
```

and do the stuff you want (e.g. search) on the array you get from this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set the [AutoWordSelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.autowordselection.aspx) property to true.  Have you tried this yet?

Comment: I work with FlowDocumentScrollViewer and there is no such property.